# How to do SEO for a school web site

Tags: web, seo

I want to know, How to do SEO for a school, I have no idea about SEO and
I have not enough time to spend more time because it is all ready late for submitting the project. so i just plane to get some idea to do SEO  with meta tags so, can any one tel me how to do that.

I have used these tags

```
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://madinacc.sch.lk/" />    
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Madina Central College (National School) Madawala Official Website" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://madinacc.sch.lk/" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Madina Central College (National School)Madawala Official Website" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://madinacc.sch.lk/" />
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="@jetpack" />
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="http://madinacc.sch.lk/" />
```

Comment: this question is too broad and you have shown no effort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There have been millions of books written on this, so a quick solution is unlikely but here are my thoughts.

Whilst I am sure there are lots of things you could do and tags you could add to the `<head>` tag, I am under the impression that nowadays the algorithms of Google, among other modern search engines, are intelligent enough to rate your site properly, based on the ACTUAL content of your site.

Given this, my advice would be to include the **well-written content** that your site NEEDS.

If you do this, your site will be ranked properly in due course.

The good thing is that much of modern SEO involves improving the site for your users. Such as:

- Having good, relevant content
- Having a fast, well performing site
- Having content that updates frequently. I.e even just a blog or similar
- Properly labelling images (title, alt-text)
- Ensuring that all the links on your page are correct! (Obvious but often overlooked)

There are a million others but they are the ones that spring to mind.